# Users of a specific role on a map with proximity search

Tags: users, google-maps, javascript

I need to create a "find a doctor near you" kind of thing.  We will have registered users that when given a specific role, will be put on the find list.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

And a couple of specifics:  Since the site will use Ubercart, it will be using the address field rather than location module.  So I currently have address field, geofield, geocoder and openlayers installed.  But I am having a hard time getting my head around it.